# How to extract XML data from ISBNDB.com API using VBA?

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

I have never worked with XML before and while I keep trying to piece together things on the net, I am getting nowhere (and in more ways than one!)

I am trying to set up a vba module that will run when someone clicks a button on Access form. The function will use the passed ISBN# and with the ISBNDB.com API return the different attributes of the book.

I've already got my Access String for the API: **https://isbndb.com/api/books.xml?access_key=NSOY388Z&results=texts&index1=isbn&value1=0007102968**

I need to know how to go about using the data to parse what is returned into one of my tables, such as Title, Author, Publisher, etc.

Here is the visual tree that is returned by my Access String:

[image]

Can anyone assist me with this? As said, I keep trying to piece the process together from the web and am getting absolutely nowhere.

Comment: Try enabling reference to `Microsoft XML, v6.0`. This gives you a good object model to work with instead of trying to parse the XML as ordinary string data. I have only used it once or twice, so I can't be of much more assistance but that's where I'd start, using a `DOM` document to read the XML rather than string parsing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load an XML DOM document from your URL, then use its methods to access text from selected nodes.  The following sample uses XPath to identify the nodes, but other methods are available, too: `getElementsByTagName`; `SelectNodes`; etc.

I wrote this sample with late binding.  You may prefer to develop with early binding while you explore the document methods and properties ... set a reference for *Microsoft XML*.

```vb
Dim strUrl As String
Dim strXPathBase As String

' early binding requires reference to Microsoft XML
'Dim objDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
'Set objDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument

' late binding, no reference required
Dim objDoc As Object
Set objDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

strUrl = "https://isbndb.com/api/books.xml" & _
    "?access_key=NSOY388Z&results=texts" & _
    "&index1=isbn&value1=0007102968"

objDoc.async = False
objDoc.Load strUrl

strXPathBase = "//ISBNdb/BookList/BookData/"
Debug.Print "Title: " & _
    objDoc.SelectSingleNode(strXPathBase & "Title").Text
Debug.Print "Publisher: " & _
    objDoc.SelectSingleNode(strXPathBase & "PublisherText").Text

Set objDoc = Nothing
```